# Windows phone screen lock unlock event handling

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Can anyone please tell me how can I stop reloading my page on screen unlock?

Everytime when I navigate to a page and then lock-unlock the screen the page is getting reloaded.

How can I modify this?

Comment: Can you add your code? Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: What's the Code in the `OnNavigatedTo` function ?